# what is the equivalent of python id in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In python you can get a unique numeric ID for any object via `id(object)`:

```py
person = Person()
person_id = id(person)
```

What is the equivalent function in Kotlin?

Comment: Kotlin is not Python, so don't expect there to be an exact equivalent. if you are targeting the JVM, you can use `System.idenittyHashCode`, but that only guarantees different ids imply different objects not the other way around. Can you explain why do you need this?

Comment: I have some objects that I create to essentially represent variables (in an AST type of structure), but I don't want to make names required. For debugging, I want to print these variable objects, and something like `id` would be helpful to distinguish between different (unnamed) variables.

Comment: If it is just for debugging purposes, then `System.identityHashCode` should be fine. Are you using Kotlin/JVM or Kotlin/Native or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Classes in Kotlin do not automatically have a unique ID. As mentioned in the comments, you can get the `identityHashCode`. It is not guaranteed unique, but in practice if you are just using it to compare items in a log, it is probably sufficient.

```
class Person() {
    val id: Int get() = System.identityHashCode(this)
}
```

If you need unique IDs, you could assign them at construction time using a counter in a companion object.

```
class Person() {
    val id: Long = nextId

    companion object {
        private var nextId: Long = 0L
            get() = synchronized(this) { ++field }
            set(_) = error("unsupported")
    }
}

// Or simpler on JVM:
class Person() {
    val id: Long = idCounter.getAndIncrement()

    companion object {
        private val idCounter = AtomicLong(1L)
    }
}
```

Or if you are on JVM, you can use the UUID class to generate a statistically unique ID for each class as it is instantiated, but this is probably not very useful just for logging.

```
class Person() {
    val id = UUID.randomUUID()
}
```